# Error while importing a file from another folder in the same project

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error while importing a file from another folder in the same project:

> Unable to resolve ./src/components/Header" from ".//App.js: could not resolve `/Users/abhinav/myProject/src/components/Header' as a file nor as a folder","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]},"type":"bundling_error"}"*

The file is already present in the required location

Answer (score 0):

Just remove that file reference from XCode(not from project folder of system)

After that, From project navigator right click the folder where you want to add the file. And Select option "Add file to " and select same file, which is available in you project folder.

It's reference issue, mostly happening in XCode 9.